# Сборка с помощью gulp данных из разных директорий

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

У меня есть подобная структура проекта

```
./source/
./source/shop/
./source/site/

./build/
./build/shop/
./build/site/
```

В source лежат исходники, которые должны после некоторых модфикаций выплевываться в build. За модификации отвечает gulp. Количество подпапок в source (и в build) соотстветвенно может меняться и каждый раз не хочется переписывать конфиг вручную. Поэтому я при помощи nodejs проверяю какие у меня есть папки в `./source/` и формирую примерно вот такой кофиг

```
config = {
    source: {
        shop: {
            templates: 'path',
            ...
        },
        site: {
            templates: 'path',
            ...
        }
    },
    build {
        shop: {
            templates: 'path',
            ...
        },
        site: {
            templates: 'path',
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

У меня задача правильно все это собирать в зависимости от того, что я хочу. И в связи с этим я сталкиваюсь с двумя задачами, к которым не знаю как подойти.

Во-первых, я хочу запускать сборку подобным образом:

```
# Собирает всё
npm run build

# Собирает только необходимый мне модуль
npm run build shop
```

Но я не знаю можно ли так вообще сделать, а если можно, то нужно будет передавать последнюю часть в gulp, а как это делать непонятно.

Во-вторых, не хочется плодить под каждый модуль задачу потому что все это может меняться. Ну то есть вот так не очень:

```
gulp.task('templates:shop', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.source.shop)
        .gulp.dist(config.build.shop)
});
```

Плохо это потому что если я добавлю в source еще один модуль, например blog, то приется лезть в gulpfile.js и package.json и дописывать какой-то код, чтобы новый модуль поддерживался, а этого бы не хотелось. Возможно есть какое-то готовое решение для подобных задач, но я так ничего не смог найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение, не знаю насколько это хорошо, но это работает. Я приведу примерный код, чтобы можно было понять суть, у меня в проекте все сложнее несколько.

gulpfile.js

```
// Для работы с файловой системой
import fs from 'fs';

// Тут понятно ;-)
import gulp from 'gulp';

// Чтобы получать аргументы
import { argv } from 'yargs';

// Получаем список модулей
const modules = fs.readdirSync('./source').filter(file => {
    return fs.statSync('./source' + file).isDirectory();
});

// Проверяем есть ли такой модуль и выводим ошибку, если запустили с несуществующим
if(argv.module && !~apps.indexOf(argv.module)) {
    throw new TypeError('Ошибка при билде несуществующего приложения ' + argv.module);
}

gulp.task('default', () => {
    // Пробегаемся по всем модулям
    modules.forEach(module => {
        // Если мы билдим не все, а только один модуль и сейчас в массиве пробегаемся не по этому модулю, то выходим, чтобы не сработала команда
        if( !(argv.module && argv.module === module || !argv.module) ) return;

        // Собираем пути, у меня это делает отдельная функция, но идея такая же
        const srcPath = './source/' + module;
        const destPath = './build/' + module;

        // Запускаем обработчик
        gulp.src(srcPath)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath));
    });
});
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel-node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js"
}
```

У меня тут Babel, чтобы работал ES6, но можно и без него в принципе.

Ну и запускается вот так:

```
# Собирает всё
npm run build

# Собирает только необходимый мне модуль
npm run build -- --module=site
```

Команда запуска билда конкретного модуля выглядит не так красиво, как я хотел изначально, но такой вариант меня тоже устроил.